# dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.9.9-2_all.deb: error creating hard link './usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/README'

Tags: linux, kali-linux, python, dpkg, python3

I want to install `python3-distutils` on my Kali Linux. But when I type the command `sudo apt install python3-distutils`, it gives the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.9.7-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 error creating hard link './usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/README': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.9.7-1_all.deb
```

What should I do?